# (Billingsley, 2nd ed, 1968) D space, (12.33) inequality proof

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

**Convergence of probability measures, Billingsley, 2nd ed, p132, Theorem 12.4**

This is what I want to prove where $x \in D \equiv$ the set of cadlag functions defined on $[0,1]$ and $w_x^{''}(\delta) \equiv \sup\{ \big|x(t)-x(t_1)\big|\wedge \big| x(t)-x(t_2)\big|: 0 \le t_1 \le t \le t_2 \le 1, t_2-t_1 \le \delta \}$.

The key idea of the proof is like:

case 1)

====

> $\big|x(s)-x(t_1)\big| \le w_x^{''}(\delta)$ and $\big| x(t)-x(t_2)\big|\le w_x^{''}(\delta)$

The result is quite trivial from $a \vee b \le a+b$

case2)

===

> $\big|x(s)-x(t_1)\big| > w_x^{''}(\delta)$ and $\big| x(t)-x(t_2)\big| > w_x^{''}(\delta)$

Since $\big|x(s)-x(t_1)\big|\wedge \big| x(s)-x(t_2)\big| \le w_x^{"}(\delta)$ and  $\big|x(s)-x(t_1)\big| > w_x^{''}(\delta)$ , we get $\big| x(s)-x(t_2)\big| \le w_x^{"}(\delta)$.

With similar argument, we get $\big| x(s)-x(t)\big| \le w_x^{"}(\delta)$.

Thus, using triangular inequality,

$\big| x(t)-x(t_2)\big| \le \big| x(t)-x(s)\big| + \big| x(s)-x(t_2)\big| \le 2w_x^{"}(\delta)$

By symmetry, we also obtain $\big| x(s)-x(t_1)\big| \le 2w_x^{"}(\delta)$, which concludes the proof of case 2.

case 3) (where my question appears)

===

> $\big|x(s)-x(t_1)\big| \le w_x^{''}(\delta)$ and $\big| x(t)-x(t_2)\big| > w_x^{''}(\delta)$

I don't know how I get the upper bound of $\big|x(t)-x(t_2)\big|$. In fact, this book seems to close the proof at the case 2.

Any comments would be helpful so much.

Comment: I would say that Billingley actually uses the inequality $$|x(t_2)-x(t)| \wedge |x(t_1)-x(s)| \leq 2w_{x}''(\delta)$$ (i.e. min instead of max) in his proof, but perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: I think so, thanks! It is very hard to believe the author made a typo.

Comment: Is it? In most of the books, there are a lots of typos around.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. I checked the context, and it makes sense to see it as a typo

Comment: Yeah, that's also what I did.